# Asyncio. Как указать параметр phone?

Tags: python, sqlite, asyncio, aiohttp

Как правильно передать значение `phone` в базу данных(в ответе значения `phone` нет)?

```
def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for i in some_one_info:
        global phone
        phone = int(i)
        tasks.append(session.post(website, headers=headers, data={"phoneNumber": f"{phone}"}, ssl=False))
    return tasks


async def kiklop():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        connect_sql = sqlite3.connect(r'C:...\exemple.db')
        cursor = connect_sql.cursor()
        for response in data:
            json_response = await response.json()
            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            today = date.today()
            d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            pool_time = f"{current_time}|{d1}"
            tlt = []
            name_add = []
            for info in json_response:
                try:
                    name = info["Name"]
                    title = info['title']
                    name_add.append(name)
                    tlt.append(title)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            try:
                name_first_str = name_add[0]
                jst_name = "".join(name_first_str)
                titles = ",".join(tlt)
                print(jst_name, titles, **phone**, pool_time)
                cursor.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO exemple (name,title,phoneNumber,date)
                                                           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                                                           """, (jst_name, titles, **phone**, pool_time))
            except Exception as e:
                cursor.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO exemple (phoneNumber,date)
                                                           VALUES (?,?)
                                                           """, (**phone**, pool_time,))

            connect_sql.commit()


def main():
    asyncio.run(kiklop())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В `run`я получаю одно значение `phone`на всех пользователях.

```
jst_name1 titles1 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
jst_name2 titles2 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
jst_name3 titles3 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
jst_name4 titles4 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
jst_name5 titles5 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
jst_name6 titles6 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
```

Необходимо, чтобы каждый номер соответствовал своему порядку:

```
 jst_name1 titles1 phone1 22:17:29|06/11/2022
 jst_name2 titles2 phone2 22:17:29|06/11/2022
 jst_name3 titles3 phone3 22:17:29|06/11/2022
 jst_name4 titles4 phone4 22:17:29|06/11/2022
 jst_name5 titles5 phone5 22:17:29|06/11/2022
 jst_name6 titles6 phone6 22:17:29|06/11/2022
```

Comment: Вместо session.post используйте свою функцию, которая станет task'ом, вы ей как параметры передадите session и phone, она в свою очередь выполнит session.post и вернет в качестве результата например тупл (phone, результат_post)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но я не  совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. 
Не могли указать на ту часть кода, где необходимо исправить ошибку или просто изменить кусок кода для наглядного примера ?